# A dimension formula for generalised symmetric powers of the natural module

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I need a reference for the following well-known statement - does anyone know one?

Let $\mu$ a partition of $n$  into at most $d$ parts.
 We let 
 $${\rm Sym}^\mu(\Bbbk^d)={\rm Sym}^{\mu_1}(\Bbbk^d) \otimes \dots \otimes {\rm Sym}^{\mu_d}(\Bbbk^d)$$
 denote the  generalised symmetric   tensor of the natural $\rm GL_d$-module, $\Bbbk^d$.
We let 
 $\rm SStd(\lambda,\mu)$ 
denote the set of semistandard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ an weight $\mu$.
  We have that 
$$  \sum_\lambda|\rm SStd(\lambda,\mu)| | SStd(\lambda,\nu)|
=\dim_\Bbbk({\rm Sym}^\mu(\Bbbk^d))
$$

Comment: Oops.  What a dunce.  This is just Young's rule.